# Android create transition from Image

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, transition

I'm creating an Android game that has a menu screen, loading screen, and game screen. The game is based around shooting bubbles so I want to have a bubble animation to transition from the menu screen to the loading screen. Ideally, whenever I click the play button to switch to the loading screen, this bubble image would rise up from the bottom to the top as a transition:[image]

Right now I am using Android XML animations by calling:

```
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

where slide_in_up is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and slide_out_up is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Can someone tell me how to make an animation that include the image passing from bottom through the top please? Thanks.

Comment: you need to animate the ImageView ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

slider.xml:(put this in res/anim folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" >
    </translate>

</set>
```

Put In onCreate()

```
Animation animationobj = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slider);
```

Put this OnButtonClick:

```
void animation_expand() 
        {               
            imgview.startAnimation(animationobj);
            animationobj.setFillAfter(true);
            animationobj.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
            });
        }
```